# How to change background color for each two rows in SSRS in a group

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, background-color

How can I write the expression in order to change background color for each two rows in SSRS?
I need something like that:
[image]

I tried expression

```
=IIF(Fields!Type.Value="2016 Submitted" , "LightBlue",
IIF(Fields!Type.Value="2015 Submitted" , "LightBlue",
 Nothing))
```

But because some months dont have values it looks like this:
[image]

If I try this expression I get below:

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!Count.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing) MOD 2 = 1, "White", "PaleTurquoise")
```

[image]

Dance-Henry I tried your code

```
=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 4 = 1 or RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 4 = 2, "Aqua","White")
```

and this is what i got:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going thru the link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrishays/2004/08/30/green-bar-matrix/

Tested and it works well for the Green Bar Effect for Matrix. I will show it step by step here as for later reference.

**Step 1**: Create the Matrix and add one more column under the innermost row grouping in your matrix. (`ColorNameTextbox` here)
[image]

**Step 2**: Select the textbox of `ColorNameTextbox` and press `F4` to setup `BackgroundColor` property as `=Value` shown below.

[image]

**Step 3**: Select the textbox of Matrix cell and press `F4` to setup `BackgroundColor` property as `=ReportItems!ColorNameTextbox.Value` shown below.

[image]

**Step 4**: Drag the inner grouping header (`ColorNameTextbox`) to be as narrow as possible.

[image]

**Step 5**: Preview Pane to check the result.

[image]

Comment: Great! Exactly what I need. Works perfectly. Also instead of narrowing the column you can just hide it (column visibility). 
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

You can select the row in design pane and press `F4` to setup property `BackgroundColor` as `=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 4 = 1 or RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 4 = 2, "Aqua","White")`

Captures are attached. Do it accordingly.

[image]

[image]

**RESULT** is something like this

[image]

Comment: Because of some months dont have values Im getting mess. Picture attached

Comment: Have you tried my code? My DAX query is just based on the table rownumber, not the text box value.

Comment: You can select the row in design pane and press F4 to setup property BackgroundColor as =IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 4 = 1 or RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 4 = 2, "Aqua","White") as captures attached.

Comment: take it easy, let me check. :)

Comment: Check this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrishays/2004/08/30/green-bar-matrix/

Comment: Thanks. Seems pretty confusing at first look, but I'll have some time to figure it out. Thanks again

Comment: @Oleg, I add a new answer step by step, I hope it will help you to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

If you could add a hidden color_group column and populate it with a new number at each point you want to change the color (in your case 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4) then you could use something like the following (which works for varying size groups):

```
IIF(RunningValue(Fields!color_group.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing) MOD 2 = 1, "White", "PaleTurquoise")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I could not come up with alternating rows because my data has Column Groups that were the `RowNumber(Nothing)` method to fail. Learning from all the other posts here this is how I resolved it in steps.

1. I added the following code into the report properties, that provides a function to get the row number, each time it is called. The function increments the row count each time it is called. >>Right click space around the report >> Properties >> Code. Alternatively go to Code Properties Window, when the report is selected.

[image]

Add the following lines:

```
 
     Public  Row_Sum As Decimal = 0
     Public Function Lookup_Sum( ) As integer
       Row_Sum = Row_Sum + 1 
       Return Row_Sum
     End Function
```

2. I added a new column at the beginning of the rows called No. that would calculate and show the row number.Right click the first column >>Insert Column>>Inside Group-Left.

[image]

3. On the expression for the new report add this line of code. Also take a note of the name of the TextBox that will have the No. Value. It will be needed in the next step. In my case the TextBox is called *TextBox6* (Properties Window). >>Right Click Cell>>Expression.

[image]

Add the code:

```
=Code.Lookup_Sum()
```

4. I highlighted the entire row and went to the Background property and added the following expression to compute the row number.

[image]

Add the code(*TextBox6* is the name Textbox name noted above):

```
=IIF(VAL(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) MOD 2, "LIGHTBLUE", "WHITE")
```